# Split Typescript logic into several files

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I have several **typescript files** in my project and one entry file `index.ts` (output file is created by [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)).

Individual files with logic `export` nothing.

Eg. `file-one.ts`:

```js
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
    console.log('Hello world');
}
```

How can I import files like the one above into main - entry file?

Eg. `index.ts`:

```
import `./file-one`
```

Return ERROR:

```sh
ERROR in ./src/index.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './file-one.ts' in './src/index.ts'
```

Comment: Maybe without the extension: `import "./file-one"`.

Comment: a function or variable need to be exported in order to be imported in another. what are you trying to export? the function (console.log) or the action of setting the onclick

Comment: Your syntax is fine (despite what the other comments say). This error simply means your build cannot resolve the file path. Need more info about your setup (webpack, tsconfig, commands used, etc).

Comment: @Paleo I made mistake when I copied code here. I just had `import `./file-one` and it was a problem source.

Comment: @AaronBeall Thank. You have right. It was configuration problem. I missed `resolve: {extensions: ['.ts']}` in my **webpack.config.js** file

Answer (score 0):

Eg. `file-one.ts`:

```js
export click() {
    console.log('Hello world');
}
```

How can I import files like the one above into main - entry file?

Eg. `index.ts`:

```
import {click} from  `./file-one.ts`

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = click;
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to do that without any problem... a module can be imported even if it is not exporting anything.

I noticed that you are using a back-tick here ... it should be a string like import './file-one.ts' ( though a back-tick in that case should raise another error)

Anyway just make sure your webpack configuration can load typescript files, and that the path to your file is correct, and it should work.

Comment: You're using an invalid extension.

Comment: You have right. It was configuration problem. I missed `resolve:{extensions:['.ts']}` in my **webpack.config.js** file

Comment: @AluanHaddad i dont get it ... what do you mean?

Comment: @ehab it is a TypeScript error to use a module specifier that ends in `.ts`. Module specifiers may explicitly end with `.js` or omit the extension and entirely rely on loader configuration to infer it but `import './module.ts';` is an error.

Comment: @AluanHaddad regardless of the typescript spec, i'm sure that you can load the file with .ts extension in webpack. In fact what you are saying in webpack is incorrect, if the file is without specific extension, and you did not configure webpack to load such files, then your build proccess will fail.

Comment: No, I'm just suggesting that you don't recommend it. Webpack has every right and plenty of reason to be agnostic about file extensions, in fact it has to be for it to work, but you should write well form typescript and you can do that by using webpack to resolve options to omit the extension. I didn't vote against this answer